# 'Approaches introduced' or 'Introduced approaches'

Tags: word-order

I have the following sentence and need help from you:

> "All *introduced approaches* lead to good results."

Is it correct to use it this way or do I have to say:

> "All *approaches introduced* lead to good results."

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past participle after noun: "proposed cost" vs. "cost proposed".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63972/past-participle-after-noun-proposed-cost-vs-cost-proposed) Also [Order of participial adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95916/order-of-participial-adjective) and [Putting “interested” before the noun.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56098/putting-interested-before-the-noun)

Answer (score -1):

From this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introduced+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintroduced%3B%2Cc0) can be extracted the following cases.

- the impact of introduced plants
- ~ Forest Trees
- ~ trees of Central California
- ~ Mammals of the world
- ~ Species in the Nordic Countries
- Guide to ~ Pest Animals
- ~ animals
- New Record of ~ Hosts for thr Mountain Pine Beetle
- ~ weeds
- ~ Plants and Animals
  …

There is not a single case of this participial adjective being used as a postmodifier. The same is true for all participial adjectives except when they have a complement; they are then placed after and are not considered as adjectives but as the verbal form in an adjectival participial phrase.

- All approaches introduced first/with haste/prematurely/etc. lead to …

Comment: Thanks LPH for your answer. Unfortunately I have to admit that I do not understand your answer at all. So would you rather use 'All introduced approaches...' or 'All approaches introduced...'?

Comment: @PeterBe Only 'All introduced approaches...'; apparently, there are no exceptions to the rule of placing the participial adjectives before, as for normally all adjectives. this is true for -ing and -ed adjectives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer LPH. What if the sentence would be: "All introduced approaches by NAME". Would you then change it to "All approaches introduced by NAME"?

Comment: @PeterBe Right. That's exactly what I was trying to explain; your example is another instance of this principle.

Comment: Thanks LPH for your comment. If I understood correctly you would use "All approaches introduced by NAME" but without the NAME you would use 'All introduced approaches...'

Comment: @PeterBe That is correct.

Comment: Without context, both seem unnecessarily ambiguous. “Every approach introduced has lead to a  good result.” I.e.Everything we tried, each separately, had a positive impact. We can do no wrong. Or”All of the approaches introduced have (collectively) had a positive impact.”  We don’t know what did the trick, but it was definitely something we did.  I would revise the sentence for clarity.

Comment: @AaronK I think the problem is understanding according to what notions past participles used on their own can be postponed: some can and numbers of them can't: http://ijssh.org/papers/159-A10025.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for the article, it was edifying w/r/t postpositional pp. It is not clear that it answer this question. It confirms that *Introduced* may be used in post-position as it is a transitive action v. w/o preposition. It is in 2+ of the author’s v. groups (“Giving” and “Doing”) But which sounds better? And why? The article posits something vague about precision in describing temporary conditions true with respect to some comparative or statistic. “The grapes produced are small.” (Up to now.) The produced grapes are small. (By nature.) Which is my point that the context and meaning are key.

Comment: @AaronK The article itself (now some 8 years old)  does make clear that there is presented in it no more than a first attempt at clarifying the question and that more research must be awaited before more useful results appear (if any such are obtainable: there is no certitude that postposition is adhered to according to any solid systematic). Classifying "introduced" can begin with "give verbs", agreed. However, there is no certitude that this verb has been found in postposition with any relevant frequency; personally, in my search for understanding I found hardly  ( after a new (1/4)

Comment: @AaronK  any case: after a verification, just 2 cases (and one appears to be journalese), "Bills Introduced and Laws Enacted Relating to Railway ...", "News Release: Bill to Amend Copyright Act Introduced" (no clue as to why). There is no doubt that pre-position "sounds" very acceptable; nevertheless, how it "sounds" is a rather subjective criterion, too much subject to the feeling of naturalness as hammered into the readers by dint of repetition. I can say personally that the two examples just mentioned do not "sound" at all unnatural to me. (2/4)

Comment: @AaronK  I just can't see what is being said that could be different. The criterion of permanence does not apply to "introduced". I agree that the context and meaning should  correspond to the syntax and that the syntax should be tuned to the meaning, but language has been modified for centuries because it has been found to fail to comply to ever new and better standards. One thing is clear: the teaching establishment hasn't been able for decades and decades to derive the principles that rule this placement (3/4)

Comment: @AaronK and they certainly would have liked to resolve that issue, on which, the author tells us, the students never receive  directives: that is quite possibly no coincidence, there might be no principle to speak of as relates to context and meaning. (4/4)